# Magento 2 system configuration changes not applying

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, system-config

Magento 2 I am trying to change ups licence number and user is after saving it not showing values it showing blank can any one tell why it happening

Comment: check error log or javascript errors

Comment: nothing is showing in error logs.No information in logs

Answer (score 0):

this is related to

> Input variables exceeded

increase `max_input_vars` in php.ini

or

javascript / ajax issue, open developer toolbar in chrome [F12], Neworking tab.
click save and look for requests with error